# how to write an if condition in Laravel Validation to execute if and only if all attributes fail

Tags: validation, laravel

I want to redirect a user to another page, if he enters duplicate data to 5 attributes (if duplicated only for 4 or less, he should not be redirected).
I'm trying to do it using laravel 5.1's built in Validator.

```
    $failure = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'firstName' => 'unique:registrations',
        'lastName' => 'unique:registrations',
        'line1' => 'unique:registrations',
        'city' => 'unique:registrations',
        'country' => 'unique:registrations'
    ]);
```

how to write an if condition to execute if all of the 5 attributes above fail,

```
if ($failure->fails())
```

this code executes if at least one attribute fails. Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $check = $failure->errors();

    if ($check->has('firstName') && $check->has('lastName') && $check->has('line1') && $check->has('city') && $check->has('country')) {   

        return redirect('<path>');
    }
```

this worked

Answer (score 1):

```
list($key,$messages) = array_divide($failure->errors()->toArray());
if($key == ['firstname','lastname','line1','city','country']){
    //all has failed
}
```

Comment: I didn't check if your answer is correct, I just got some ideas from your answer, thank you!!! (Y)

Answer (score 0):

If no matter what attributes are duplicated more suitable way:

```
if (count($failure->getMessageBag()) >= 4) {
    return ...
}
```

If only for some fields, more beautiful way:

```
if($validator->getMessageBag()->has(['firstName', 'lastName', 'line1', 'city', 'country'])) {
   return ...
}
```

You can use `errors()` or `getMessageBag()` - it's no matter :)